# How to calculate how fast a set of numbers goes towards zero?

Tags: calculus

I have the given set of numbers in the table below [image: Table]. I would like to calculate how fast these numbers of $DetA_n^{(1)}$ are approaching zero as N decreases or increases.

For example between N= -19 and-20 they approach zero faster than between N = -17 and N=-18. The same  applies for other intervals of N. How can this be organized in a graph or formula?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have a negative value for $N=15$.  These numbers will have an upper bound of the form $k c^{|N|}$ for some $0<c<1$ but it is difficult to tell just from a picture of a table, and you cannot guarantee what happens for larger $|N|$

Comment: If you take the ratio of consecutive terms for the large values of $N$, you can see that your values are decreasing by a factor of slightly less than $5$. E.g., $3.155...'06333...\approx4.98...$. By computing the ratio for all $N$'s, you can see if there's any trend. But in the absence of other knowledge of what you're computing, it's unlikely any conclusive pattern will emerge. (I assume the minus sign in the $N=15$ term is a typo. If not, then something really strange is happening there.)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

As Henry was suggesting, one can conjecture that these values go to 0 as $k c^{|N|}$. Then, one can hope to find the values of $c$ and $k$. You can do the following.

We conjecture $|DetA_N^{(1)}| \sim k c^{|N|}$.

Taking the logarithms, $\log(|DetA_N^{(1)}|) \sim \log(k c^{|N|})=\log(k)+\log(c)|N|$. (Here I am thinking about the natural logarithm, but it works for any other base).

This means that, if you take the logarithm of your data and you plot them in the plane, they should behave like lines, at least away from N=0, that is a sort of stationary value.

Then, if the conjecture is true, you should be able to determine log(c) and log(k) looking at this plot. If you want a somewhat "rigorous answer" you can take the linear regression of these values. Then, just take the exponentials of the two logs to obtain the desired constants.

Clearly, when doing this, you have to split the two cases, $N<0$ and $N>0$, because the behaviours are different, and there will be two different lines. In principle, $c$ and $k$ could be different for these two cases.

For more ideas about this approach, I suggest watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hl5KtXyNvA&t=543s

**Edit:**

A simpler thing that you can do is to take the ratio between consecutive terms and see at what it converges. In this way, you should obtain $c$.

Precisely, let's call $a_N:=|DetA_N^{(1)}|$. Let's assume $N>0$ for simplicity.

Then, $\frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N}\sim\frac{k c^{N+1}}{k c^{N}}=c$.

So, just taking the values $\frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N}$ for all positive $N$, they should converge to something non-zero if the conjecture is true. I guess the constant $c$ in this kind of estimate is more important than k, and surely easier to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to others for their ideas. I found a solution.

I calculated the successive differences between each value of $|DetA|$. Then I interpolated the points, and found it gives two piecewise plots. Then I  did a regression for each of the two sets of points of $|DetA|$ between N= -20 to 0, and N=0 to 20. This gave a clear exponential decay, with two specified functions in the form :

$F(t)=Ae^{Bt} for -20<N<0$

$G(t)=Ce^{Et} for 0<N<20$